# Free unallocated space can be added to swap but not ext4

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu on my windows machine with dual boot and have managed to reach size limit of the disc space that I allocated. I want to extend this disc space and whenI open up the discs utility I see the following:

[image]

It looks like I have 19.53gb unallocated space which I would like to allocate to `/dev/nvme0n1p4` where the rest of my Ubuntu things are.

When I try to allocate more space the option to do so is greyed out (as if there is no free space to allocate at all). What's also interesting is that I have another drive called `/dev/nvme0n1p5` which is in swap format (that I think I created as for additional memory when setting up Ubuntu) which IS available to use up this unallocated space.

Why would that drive be allowed to use up the allocated space but not my main drive?

Thanks!

Comment: Woops, yea not sure why but a mistake!

Comment: To modify the Ubuntu partition you have to do it from an Ubuntu live media, you can't do it while you are using it. To resize a partition there's must be *contiguous* space unallocated. So you have two partitions surrounding the unallocated space, p5 and p6, p5 with the flag swap but filesystem unknown... I don't know why... and p6 could be some windows related partition? The thing is, if you can safely delete these two partitions then you can resize p4.

Comment: This was the correct answer, I only had to remove p5 as that was the only one between them. If you answer the question I will mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Windows and seeing if it's possible in the Disk Management Tool

Which looks like this:
[Windows Disk Management Tool Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHCMM.png)

Comment: It can be done, but not good idea.  Two separate and different OSs and each have tools/programs to work well with their own OS.  Trying to work with other OS not as good as their own.  Windows tools for windows, linux tools for linux.

Comment: yeah definitely not ideal, but could be worth a shot

Comment: Yea I already tried that and no joy I'm afraid. I can't allocate it to windows drive either :/